# How do I gradually apply velocity in Spigot?

Tags: velocity, minecraft, bukkit

I am using `player.setVelocity(player.getLocation().getDirection().multiply(Main.instance.getConfig().getDouble("velocity_multiplier")).setY(Main.instance.getConfig().getInt("Y_axis")));` to set velocity to a player. It allows high configuration of movement via config, but the problem is that when you set it too high, Spigot blocks it. I do not want to enable:

> server.properties: allow_flight.

So how can I avoid this? I bumped up the multiplier to 30 just for a test, and it would start to move you, glitch, and pull you back down. It also says that the player moved too quickly in console even from smaller amounts of velocity. I was thinking of making it gradually apply the velocity. When you jump, it applies the starting velocity and as you go it goes higher(Y_axis) and farther(velocity_multiplier), but I do not know how to do that.

Comment: You said that maybe it is because of allow_flight is false?! Why you don't try to set allow_flight to true while the player is flying? Player.setAllowFlight(true);

Comment: If you want to enable flight without setting it in the config why create a custom flying system? Just simple do what nightfighter said using `player.setAllowFlight(boolean allow);` this will allow the player to fly without causing any active hack protections to glitch(Unless there bad). || Could you tell me why you need this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beyond code, you likely would be best situated to address your issue by allowing flight in the Spigot file and installing or developing an anti-cheat in the game. Spigot's flight protection works poorly with many plugins and does not successfully block many players who attempt to fly.

Best advice would be to look beyond a makeshift code solution and rather create your own anti-fly.

Comment: Comment quality answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can enable just for the player  before applying the velocity and in a delayed task disabled it

```
public void blabla(Player player){
   player.setAllowFlight(true);
        player.setVelocity(player.getLocation().getDirection().multiply(Main.instance.getConfig().getDouble("velocity_multiplier")).setY(Main.instance.getConfig().getInt("Y_axis")));
        new BukkitRunnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                player.setAllowFlight(false);

            }
        }.runTaskLater(this, 20 * 5);
}
```

In the code I used 20 * 5 to disable the flight after 5 seconds, you can change it to what you want.

Comment: I'll do it when I go home

Comment: Added it now, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum velocity in bukkit (and spigot) is 10 blocks per tick. This is all directions combined.

If your initial velocity is to high, you can use the scheduler to repeatedly calculate the next velocity.

To calculate this, we need some magic values: The following values come from [The Minecraft Wiki](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Transportation#Vertical_speeds).

```
private final static double DECELERATION_RATE = 0.98D;
private final static double GRAVITY_CONSTANT = 0.08D;
private final static double VANILA_ANTICHEAT_THRESHOLD = 9.5D; // actual 10D
```

We first need to calculate the spot the player would reach using those speeds, and then teleport him while applying the velocity for the first part.

We are going to use a `BukkitRunnable` to run a task that calculates the above:

```
Vector speed = ...;
Player player = ...;
new BukkitRunnable() {
    double velY = speed.getY();
    Location locCached = new Location(null,0,0,0);
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (velY > VANILA_ANTICHEAT_THRESHOLD) {
            player.getLocation(locCached).setY(locCached.getY() + velY);
            player.teleport(locCached);
            player.setVelocity(new Vector(0,ANILA_ANTICHEAT_THRESHOLD,0));
        } else {
            player.setVelocity(new Vector(0,velY,0));
            this.cancel();
        }
        velY -= GRAVITY_CONSTANT;
        velY *= DECELERATION_RATE;
    }
}.runTaskTimer(plugin,0,1);
```

The above code will then handle the velocity problems for us and can be used in place of `setVelocity`.